# Replacing changing values columnwise in a DF

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2
1  6  7  8  5  4 10
2  7  8  9  6  5 11
3  8  9 10  7  6 12
4  9 10 11  8  7 13
5 10 11 12  9  8 14
6 11 12 13 10  9 15
```

Now I want to change the values in x1 and x2 according to this rule: Every value in x1 or in x2 that is greater than 8 should be subtracted by eight, every value in x1 or x2 that is smaller that is 8 or smaller should be replaced by NA. Additionally, if a value in x1 or x2 is replaced by NA y1/y2 and z1/z2 should be also set to NA. The dataframe should look like this.

```
  x1   y1 z1 x2 y2 z2
1  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
2  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
3  NA  NA NA NA NA NA
4   1 10 11  NA NA NA
5   2 11 12   1  8 14
6   3 12 13   2  9 15
```

The code to generate the dataframe

```
df1<-data.frame("x1"=6:11,"y1"=7:12,"z1"=8:13,"x2"=5:10,"y2"=4:9,"z2"=10:15)
```

Answer (score 1):

We create two indexes based for 'x1' and 'x2' and assign the values based on those index

```
i1 <- df1$x1 <=8 #x1 index
i2 <- df1$x2 <=8 #x2 index
nm1 <- grep("1$", names(df1)) #column index for suffix 1 in column names
nm2 <- grep("2$", names(df1)) #column index for suffix 2 in column names


df1[i1,nm1] <- NA #set the values for suffix 1 columns to NA
df1[i2, nm2] <- NA #set the values for suffix 2 columns to NA
df1[c('x1', 'x2')] <- df1[c('x1', 'x2')] - 8 #subtract 8 from the 'x' columns
df1
#   x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2
#1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
#4  1 10 11 NA NA NA
#5  2 11 12  1  8 14
#6  3 12 13  2  9 15
```

Comment: This answer works for this specific case, but I don't want to set the NA's by hand.

Comment: @PCK1992 We are not setting NAs' by hand.  If you look at the solution, the column names are indexed with `grep`

Answer (score 0):

We have a condition in two variables, and then a series of reactions in case of this conditions are TRUE.

```
# Activate the condition for x1 and x2
df1$x1 <- ifelse(df1$x1 > 8, df1$x1 - 8, NA)
df1$x2 <- ifelse(df1$x2 > 8, df1$x2 - 8, NA)

# Reaction of other variables to a external condition
df1$y1 <- ifelse(df1$x1 > 8, NA, df1$y1)
df1$y2 <- ifelse(df1$x2 > 8, NA, df1$y2)

# Reaction of other variables to a external condition
df1$z1 <- ifelse(df1$x1 > 8, NA, df1$z1)
df1$z2 <- ifelse(df1$x2 > 8, NA, df1$z2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df[,c("x1","x2")] <- sapply(df[,c("x1","x2")],function(x)ifelse(x>8,x-8,NA))


df %>%
  mutate(y1=replace(y1,which(x1%in%NA),NA))%>%
   mutate(z1=replace(z1,which(x1%in%NA),NA))%>%
  mutate(y2=replace(y2,which(x2%in%NA),NA))%>%
  mutate(z2=replace(z2,which(x2%in%NA),NA))

  x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2
1 NA NA NA NA NA NA
2 NA NA NA NA NA NA
3 NA NA NA NA NA NA
4  1 10 11 NA NA NA
5  2 11 12  1  8 14
6  3 12 13  2  9 15
```

Comment: @PCK1992 Hope this might be useful